# uwsgi returns 500 error after 1 minute

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I've setup a nginx+uwsgi+flask app and it works like a charm but if I load a page and load other page (or the same page) after 1 minute, uwsgi returns a 500 internal server error without any information in the logs and if I load the page it works ok.

I've noticed it only happens if the request is bound to the same pid of the last process.

This is what I'm using to start uwsgi:

```
HOSTPATH=/var/www/vhosts/example.com

uwsgi -H $HOSTPATH/httpdocs/venv -x $HOSTPATH/httpdocs/uwsgi.xml -M 4 -t 30 -A 4 -p 4  --pidfile /var/run/uwsgi.pid -d /var/log/uwsgi.log --harakiri-verbose --enable-threads --log-5xx --no-orphans
```

My uwsgi.xml:

```
<uwsgi>
  <socket>127.0.0.1:3031</socket>
  <chdir>/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/app</chdir>
  <pythonpath>..</pythonpath>
  <module>wsgi:app</module>
  <master>True</master>
</uwsgi>
```

And my nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen xx.xxx.xxx.xx:80 default_server;

    server_name example.com;
    client_max_body_size 128m;

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      127.0.0.1:3031;
        proxy_set_header X-Accel-Internal /static;
    }


    location /static {
        alias      /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/app/project/static/;
    }
}
```

Any ideas on what it could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed NewRelic and figured out the errors were MySQL timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure uWSGI is returning 500 and is not nginx doing that ? Can you enable flask debug ?

Have you checked that page: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ThingsToKnow.html

Just for curiosity, is there any specific reason for mixing xml config with command line args ?